# Is it possible to design solid slabs on ETABS 2016?

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method

My graduation project involves designing several buildings with flat and solid slabs. I already know that ETABS can design flat slabs but is it possible to design solid slabs?

Comment: What is the difference between a flat slab and a solid slab?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? It is the same thing as a solid slab just without beams.